# GSON - Not escaping unicode char

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON to serialize my object.  But some reason, it is not escaping certain unicode chars.

```
    Gson gson =  new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson("Â™"));
    System.out.println(Character.codePointAt("Â™", 0) );
    System.out.println(Character.codePointAt("Â™", 1) );
```

Output:

> "Â™"
>
> 194
>
> 8482

Is there a setting to ensure that the chars get escaped?

Comment: Care to tell _why_ you want to escape them at all?

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to escape unicode characters as they're allowed in JSON strings.

From [json.org](http://json.org/) :

[image]

If you have problems sending your JSON to the browser, check your HTTP headers are set to UTF-8.

If you really want to escape unicode characters as in Java, you might use [apache commons's StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) but you probably shouldn't.